# What does the phrase "a homomorphism which leaves elements of a ring fixed" mean?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, ring-theory

Suppose R is a subring of S and both of them are commutative. Fix $a \in S$. Define $\psi_{a}:R[x] \rightarrow S$ by $\psi_{a}(P):=P(a)$ for all $P \in R[x]$.

Question: Prove that if $\psi:R[x] \rightarrow S$ is a homomorphism which leaves elements of R fixed, then $\psi=\psi_{a}$ for some $a \in S$.

I don't really need a solution to this question, my real question is what does it mean by " $\psi$ is a homomorphism which leaves elements of R fixed"?

Comment: It means that it fixes constant polynomials in $R[x]$, so $\psi(r)=r$ for any $r\in R$.

Answer (score 2):

One can regard $R$ as a subring of $R[x]$ (as the collection of "constant"
polynomials within). By definition $R$ is a subring of $R$. So the homomorphism $\phi$ "leaves elements of $R$ fixed" if $\phi(r)=r$
for all $r\in R$. Here, on the left $r$ is a constant polynomial in $R[x]$
and on the right an element of $R\subseteq S$.

Another was of saying this is "$\phi$ is a homomorphism of $R$-algebras".

Answer (score 1):

It means (1) that $\psi$ is a homomorphism, and (2) that if $r\in R$, then $\psi(r)=r$.

Comment: but what $\psi$ consumes is elements of $R[x]$

Comment: $R$ is contained in $R[x]$..........

Comment: oh yeah..u r right